# JsonSerializer throwing org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 4000 (through reference chain: during serialization

Tags: json, spring, serialization, jackson

I'm getting

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4000

exception during JsonSerializer with a particular Object value and rest call is resulting in

> 500Internal Server Error.

below is the exception returned to Dispatcher Servlet after the call is returned back to the client from Rest API call.

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 4000 (through reference
>   chain:

I have tried upgrading the jackson jar version also from 1.9.2 to 1.9.5 and 1.9.13, but still throwing the same exception.
I have tried making all involved POJO objects as serializable also.

If I modify anything in JSON data call is successful with Response 200.
I can't use JSON ignore property also as fields all required.
The same code works fine for other transaction.

Please share some knowledge on it.

Comment: you have to provide more info on json input and pojo classes.

Comment: Making POJOs serializable will have no effect. Try putting your JSON into something like JSON Editor Online and see if that renders correctly.  Maybe you have an escape character in the source JSON data